# Call Href from Another page

Tags: html, events, hyperlink, call, article

This is my first time posting here.

My website has a portfolio page written in HTML5.  On the page, I have multiple HTML links to different galleries.

`<a href="#II">`

which presumably calls

`<article class="col2 pad_left1 tab-content" id="II">
<ul class="gallery">`

How do I directly call each gallery from an HTML link from another page?

Thanks,

Grayson

Answer (score 2):

By prepending the other page's url to the href value:

```
<a href="http://foo/other-page#middle">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a href in your link as you did. The url than looks like: www.example.com#hrefYouPut. On document ready you do an if clause:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash == "#hrefYouPut") {
        //my gallery pops up in here
    }
```